# Return statement in for loops within an function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know that my return statement is in wrong place, but can't figure out how to fix it.

Here is my code:

```
def show_Number(limit):
   for number in range(limit):
       if number % 2 == 0:
           print(f"{number} even")

       else:
           number % 2 != 0
           print(f"{number} odd")
   return number
```

I expect the output of this function to be:

```
0 even
1 odd
2 even
3 odd
4 even
```

but the actual output is:

```
0 even
1 odd
2 even
3 odd
4 even
4
```

Comment: Can you show the code calling this method? I guess you are printing the returned value, which is `4`. There's no need for you to return or print anything for this method to work as you intend. Just the `print` statements inside the method will suffice.

Comment: It seems to me that this function does not need a return statement, unless you do something with the last number later in your code

Answer (score 4):

You **do not** need a return statement there, also this `number % 2 != 0`, does nothing in the else block:

```
def show_Number(limit):
   for number in range(limit):
       if number % 2 == 0:
           print(f"{number} even")
       else:
           print(f"{number} odd")
```

Comment: A simple one-liner just for fun: `print('\n'.join(f'{number} ' + ['even', 'odd'][number%2] for number in range(limit)))`

Answer (score 0):

In that case, the return is not necessary, because you already print the results. The last 4 is the return.